# How to place the paramter of the function at the beginning

Tags: javascript

I wrote my function like this: `truncate('Hello world!, 5);`

But I want write my function like this: `'Hello world!'.truncate(5);`

```
function truncate(str, num) {
  if (str.length <= num) {
  return str
}
return str.slice(0, num) + '...'

}

console.log(truncate('Hello world!', 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prototype object to extend methods.

```
String.prototype.truncate = function(num){
    if (this.toString().length <= num) return this.toString();
    return this.toString().slice(0,num)
};
'Hello World!'.truncate(5); //  Hello
```